# Making a new worksheet for every unique name on a list but I need the worksheet to be a copy of a template

Tags: templates, macros, filter, copy, unique

I am a novice when it comes to making macros so I am in desperate need of help. I have two worksheets, one with data that will be updated with new data everyday and the other, a template that the data needs to fill in by each row accordingly. However the template needs to be a copy of the unique name from column A and renamed by that name. If the template worksheet already exist it will take the information from that matching name and copy certain information to the template. If there is no worksheet(template) existent then it will create a new worksheet according to that unique value from column "A".

The data in worksheet(data) will first need to be filtered by two types, "Redemption" and "Full Liquidation" from column "I" before it can start transferring data.

From worksheet(data) to worksheet(template),

column "A" will be the new worksheet(template) name,

column "E" will be put in Worksheet(template) column "A" starting with row 4,

column "F" will be in column "B",

column "B" will be in column "C",

column "O" will be in column "D",

column "L" will be in column "T".

So far I have this as a Macro, but it does not copy the template and it takes the whole row instead of the specific columns that I need.

```
Sub PagesByDescription()
Dim rRange As Range, rCell As Range
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim wSheetStart As Worksheet
Dim strText As String
Set wSheetStart = ActiveSheet
wSheetStart.AutoFilterMode = False
'Set a range variable to the correct item column
Set rRange = Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

    'Add a sheet called "UniqueList"
    Worksheets.Add().Name = "UniqueList"

       'Filter the Set range so only a unique list is created
        With Worksheets("UniqueList")
            rRange.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , _
             Worksheets("UniqueList").Range("A1"), True

             'Set a range variable to the unique list, less the heading.
             Set rRange = .Range("A2", .Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
        End With

        On Error Resume Next
        With wSheetStart
            For Each rCell In rRange
              strText = rCell
             .Range("A1").AutoFilter 1, strText
                Worksheets(strText).Delete
                'Add a sheet named as content of rCell
                Worksheets.Add("CLASS GROUPING ID").Name = strText
                'Copy the visible filtered range _
                (default of Copy Method) and leave hidden rows
                .UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
                ActiveSheet.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
            Next rCell
        End With

    With wSheetStart
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Activate
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Please help I'm in desperate need of some guidance

Comment: can you please check the code you have submitted? when I changed the layout of it I realised there are `End Sub` twice which is confusing...

Comment: Sorry that last is a repeat of the the last command 

[With wSheetStart .AutoFilterMode = False .Activate End With On Error GoTo 0 Application.DisplayAlerts = True End Sub]